# Read input with different datatypes and space seperation

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to write code to let the user input three values (string, int, int) in one line with space to separate the values.

I thought of doing it with String.Split Method but that only works if all the values have the same datatype.

How can I do it with different datatypes?

For example:
The user might want to input

> Hello 23 54

I'm using console application C#

Comment: All the data is a `string` until you split and attempt to parse it.

Comment: merge values into string and use Split or regex

Comment: String.Split and use int.TryParse() to see if it's an integer.

Comment: @Carra Thank you Carra. Could you give me an example?

Comment: `String.Split` works with only one data type at all: `String`. What you need to do is split the string into its parts and **then** parse the parts into their respective data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first problem is that you need to decide whether the text the user enters itself can contain spaces. For example, is the following allowed?

```
Hello World, it's me 08 15
```

In that case, `String.Split` will not really be helpful.

What I'd try is using a regular expression. The following may serve as a starting point:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^(?<text>.+) (?<num1>(\+|\-)?\d+) (?<num2>(\+|\-)?\d+)$");
if (m.Success)
{
    string stringValue = m.Groups["text"].Value;
    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["num1"].Value);
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["num2"].Value);
}
```

---

BTW: The following part of your question makes me frown:

> I thought of doing it with String.Split Method but that only works if all the values have the same datatype.

A string is always just a string. Whether it contains a text, your email-address or your bank account balance. It is always just a series of characters. The notion that the string contains a number is just your interpretation!

So from a program's point of view, the string you gave is a series of characters. And for splitting that it doesn't matter at all what the real semantics of the content are.

That's why the splitting part is separate from the conversion part. You need to **tell** your application that that the first part is a string, the second and third parts however are supposed to be numbers. That's what you need type conversions for.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten, that was really helpful. I have another question. Is it possible to save the two int values to variables?

Comment: Well, that's what my code is already doing... The `num1` and `num2` variables are filled with the `int` values from the string.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Well in that case, thank you so much. That solved it!

Comment: By the way, do you know the system reference for using Regex or regular expression? My visual studio cant seem to recognize the "Match"

Comment: @Shoxxer Add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` to your class file. I added a bit to my answer about one part of your question. Maybe you should read that for better understanding of terminology.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing things. A string is either `null`, empty or contains a sequence of characters. It never contains other data types. However, it might contain parts that could be interpreted as numbers, dates, colors etc... (but they are still strings). `"123"` is not an `int`! It is a string containing a number.

In order to extract these pieces you need to do two things:

1. Split the string into several string parts.
2. Convert string parts that are supposed to represent whole numbers into a the `int` type (=`System.Int32`).

```
string input = "Abc 123 456"
string[] parts = input.Split(); //Whitespaces are assumed as separators by default.
if (parts.Count == 3) {
    Console.WriteLine("The text is \"{0}\"", parts[0]);

    int n1;
    if (Int32.TryParse(parts[1], out n1)) {
        Console.WriteLine("The 1st number is {0}", n1);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("The second part is supposed to be a whole number.");
    }

    int n2;
    if (Int32.TryParse(parts[2], out n2)) {
        Console.WriteLine("The 2nd number is {0}", n2);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("The third part is supposed to be a whole number.");
    }
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("You must enter three parts separated by a space.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is get "Hello 23 54" in a string variable. Split by " " and treat them.

```
string value = "Hello 23 54";
var listValues = value.Split(' ').ToList();
```

After that you have to parse each item from listValues to your related types.

Hope it helps. ;)

Comment: `string[] listValues = value.Split(' ');` would be fully sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just wanted to use his example. ;)

Comment: @RafaelRibeiro Thank you Rafael, that was helpful. I have another question. Is it possible to save the two int values to variables?

Comment: Always a pleasure! ˆˆ

Comment: It's possible to put each value splitted into a array or List<object> using a foreach for example. If is this what I understood in you question. ;)